# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Post' not found in laravel-5.8

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to show data at index page but it says: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Post' not found

controller:

```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class IndexController extends Controller
  {

      public function index()
      {
          $data = Post::all();
          return view('index', compact('data'));
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following line:

```
use App\Post;
```

now your code should look like this:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Post;

  class IndexController extends Controller
  {

          public function index()
          {
              $data = Post::all();
              return view('index', compact('data'));
           }
```